# GoogleApiClient not resolving in Android Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-api

I am getting this error

"GoogleApiClient cannot be resolved to a type"

when attempting to build a new api client. I have followed the directions to the tee from this site: https://developers.google.com/places/android/start , and I believe I have done everything else necessary as far as setting up the build target to Google APIs + Android 5.1.1.

I think I have down to this error I get from the console :

invalid resource directory name: C: ... JavaWorkspace\google-play-  services_lib\res values-ne-rNP (1)

because that file does not exist in that location, but I am not sure how to resolve that.

Thanks!

Comment: Also, I am new to this, so I wasn't sure how to provide pictures and all that, but if it would be helpful I totally can.

Comment: have to referenced the google-play-services_lib into your project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, and a work around, not an actual solution though. For some reason eclipse would add a space in between res and values: C: ... JavaWorkspace\google-play- services_lib\res values-ne-rNP. I think because it was in Google Drive. So I switched my workspace and it fixed itself.